# Can find match with regex

Tags: regex

Hi I'm trying to find line start with "CGK / WIII" but just can find the the first line?

What's wrong with my text? (it is rendered from a pdf file)

[Mytext](https://regex101.com/r/gKNMV1/1)

I am coding with Python to extract data from pdf invoice to dataframe with invoice2data package, and face an error with one text rendered from one pdf file.

First I tried with regex: `\w{3}\s\/[\s\w{4}]*` and found out that it just can find 1 line.

Then I also tried with fix text "CGK / WIII" should found 4 match. But it's NOT.

I think there are font differences in my text but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I turn on `global - Don't return after the first match` in your linked example, it shows 4 matches.

Also you can not use quantifiers `{4}` inside a character set (inside `[]`).

I'd do it like [this](https://regex101.com/r/k9oC4A/1):
`\w{3}\s/\s\w{4}`